# Correct initialization of objects based on return-by-value functions

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming, return-value, return-value-optimization

I've basically the following two classes for which I use return-by-value functions to create objects.
In the Bar class below, I've two Foo class member objects. How could I initialize correctly, each of those
two objects separately?
Below, I'm giving an ilustration about the compiler error that is displayed.

```
template < typename T >
class Foo{

    public:
        Foo( );
        Foo( const Foo<T> & );
        ~Foo();

        friend Foo<T> createFoo1( double, bool );
        friend Foo<T> createFoo2( double, bool );
        friend Foo<T> createFoo3( int );

    private:

        std::vector<T> m_data;

};

template < typename T >
Foo<T> createFoo1( double param1, bool param2 ){
    Foo<T> myFoo;

    // fill myFoo.
    return (myFoo);
}

template < typename T >
class Bar{

    public:

        Bar( );
        Bar( const Foo<T> &, const Foo<T> & );
        Bar( const Bar<T> & );
        ~Bar( );

        friend Bar<T> createBar1( double, bool );

    private:
        Foo<T> m_fooY;
        Foo<T> m_fooX;
};

template < typename T >
Bar<T> createBar1( double param1, bool param2 ){
    Bar<T> myBar( createFoo1<T>(param1, param2), createFoo1<T>(param1, param2) ); //OK
    return (myBar);

    //Bar<T> myBar;
    //myBar.m_fooY(createFoo1<T>(param1, param2)); // <- error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
    //myBar.m_fooX(createFoo1<T>(param1, param2)); // <- error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
    //return (myBar);
}
```

Comment: The `// OK` line is fine, why do you need another solution?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I wanted to understand what was wrong since it was my first try.

Comment: Alright, but the `// OK` line is about the only "right" way of doing it. Don't use the other ones.

Comment: @KerrekSB, the solution given by Adam Z. below is also wrong? if yes, why?

Comment: It's not incorrect, but you would never use it like that. Always *initialize* correctly. The Adam method first default-initializes and then *assigns*. Best case that's just redundant and hard to read; worst case it simply won't work with non-default-constructible types (this includes base subobjects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can set the fields m_fooX and m_fooY other than through the constructor:

```
template < typename T >
Bar<T> createBar1( double param1, bool param2 ){
  Bar<T> myBar;
  myBar.m_fooY = createFoo1<T>(param1, param2);
  myBar.m_fooX = createFoo1<T>(param1, param2);
  return myBar;
}
```